# Find a formula for a function which must increase with $0.5$ at every step$=40$.

Tags: functions

Is there any formula which can help me to find a function which increases the function value by $0.5$ at every step of length $= 40$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$y = \dfrac{\lfloor \frac{x}{40} \rfloor}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac12 \int_0^x \delta\left(\sin\left(\frac {\pi z}{40}\right)\right)dz$$